# How to prove a simple Struve inequality

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, special-functions

It appears from the figure 11.3.4 of [dlmf](http://dlmf.nist.gov/) that the Struve function $M_1(x)$ is monotonically decreasing for positive $x$.  The asymptotic expansion (11.6.2) shows that the limit is $-2/\pi$.  So it seems clear that

$$M_1(x)>-\frac{2}{\pi},\qquad x>0$$

But, how to prove this?  Any hints or references much appreciated.

**Edit:** As indicated above, I am using dlmf definitions (11.2.2, 11.2.6):

$$M_\nu(z)=L_\nu(z)-I_\nu(z)$$ where $I$ is the modified Bessel function and

$$ L_\nu(z)=\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{\nu+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2n}}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac32\right)\Gamma\left(n+\nu+\frac32\right)}$$

is the modified Struve function.  The asymptotic expansion is given as (11.6.2):

$$ M_\nu(z)\sim\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac12\right)\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{\nu-2k-1}}{\Gamma\left(\nu+\frac12-k\right)},\qquad |z|\to\infty,\quad|\mbox{ph}(z)|\leq\frac{\pi}{2}-\delta$$

Comment: Is your $M$ written as $K$ in the reference?

Comment: No, $M$ is $M$.  Why do you think I mean $K$?

Comment: Following @FanZheng question, in both Wiki and Wolfram there are many different definitions of Struve and modified Struve functions. I think it'd be best if you write the definition of $M_1$ in the oringinal post.

Comment: OK, but it should be clear I am using dlmf definitions.

Comment: @AmirSagiv Actually I checked [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) and [wolfram](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/StruveH/introductions/Struves/02/) and it seems both have the same definition of the _H_ and _L_ functions as dlmf.